# Rails image_tag width attribute to use a percentage / auto value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`image_tag('batman.png' size:'100%xauto')`

The size 100% x Auto is ignored as it does not follow the convention outlined in the Rails API.

Is there a way to do this in rails without the need of a global / specific css class?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

size is spitted across the 'x' and on both side it finds for numbers. checkout [the code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b15ce4a006756a0b6cacfb9593d88c9a7dfd8eb0/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb#L211)
You can use 'style' option for image_tag.

UPDATE:

You can use the image tag with style as followed

```
= image_tag 'image_url', style: 'height:100%;width:auto;'
```

Comment: Thanks for that information @ravi1991, however I'm not entirely sure how to implement that into the helper image_tag.

Comment: Thanks for this, however in my question i've asked if there is a way to do it without the use of css styles.

Comment: You can any time override the helper as you want or else you can create new helper for you by changing rails helpers code ;)

Comment: ah ok, so you extend the helper if you want to support percentages and widths, thanks that makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= image_tag('batman.png', :size => '100%xauto') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<%= image_tag 'image_url', style: 'height:100%; width:auto;' %>
```

But if you don't want to write your styles inline, then you can use a `class` instead:

```
<%= image_tag 'image_url', class: 'some-class-name' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

best way is

```
  <%= image_tag avatar , height: 'value' , width: 'value can be auto or 30' %>
```